# Table Control Empty cell

Tags: abap, dynpro

In my dynpro, I have a table controller, named `TC300`, that is showing data from my database table `zma_kostl`. When I change some data in the table controller, the data will be modified even in the database table. This is true when I change the data to some other random data. But when I change the data in a cell to a blank value, the change is not propagated to a database table.

Do you have any idea why?? I think there is error somewhere in module `save_data`. Do you have any ideas, how to improve the code?

Here is my code:

Top Include:

```
FUNCTION-POOL zma_ic_screen.

TABLES  zma_kostl.

CONTROLS TC300 TYPE TABLEVIEW USING SCREEN 300.
DATA: cols LIKE LINE OF TC300-cols.

DATA it_zma_kostl TYPE TABLE OF zma_kostl.
```

Dynpro 300:

```
PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
  MODULE data_retrieval.

  LOOP AT it_zma_kostl INTO zma_kostl WITH CONTROL TC300.
  ENDLOOP.

  MODULE SET_LINES.

PROCESS AFTER INPUT.
  LOOP AT it_zma_kostl.
    MODULE read_table_control_300.
  ENDLOOP.

  MODULE SAVE_DATA.
```

Modules:

```
MODULE data_retrieval OUTPUT.
  IF it_zma_kostl IS INITIAL.
    SELECT kostl
      FROM zma_kostl
      INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE it_zma_kostl.
  ENDIF.

ENDMODULE.

MODULE read_table_control_300 INPUT.
   MODIFY it_zma_kostl FROM zma_kostl INDEX tc300-current_line.
ENDMODULE.

MODULE save_data INPUT.
  MODIFY zma_kostl FROM TABLE it_zma_kostl.
ENDMODULE.

MODULE set_lines OUTPUT.
  DATA VLINES TYPE I.
  DESCRIBE TABLE it_zma_kostl LINES VLINES.
  TC300-LINES = VLINES + 1.
  DESCRIBE TABLE it_zma_work_section LINES VLINES.
  TC400-LINES = VLINES + 1.
ENDMODULE.
```

Comment: The only idea which comes to my mind is that you emptied a field that is part of the primary key of the database table, then `MODIFY` doesn't change the old line, it creates a new one.

Comment: Another idea: maybe you look at the table contents from another session, while you have paused the debugger right after `MODIFY`, so you can't see the changes until there is a database commit.

Comment: Another idea: to continue on first idea about primary key, maybe you defined a unique secondary index on that table column, or a database constraint/trigger which fails.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a git repository of your minimal reproducible code, including the DynPro screen and the table definition, so that we can reproduce? Thanks.

Comment: you can check sy-subrc value after `MODIFY` statement in `save-data` and see if it returns smth other than 0